# cannot debug on device flash builder

Tags: android, flash, builder

I have spent a lot of time to develop a game for android devices in flash builder.

It works fine on the emulator. But when I connect my Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus, which is on the certified devices list, it shows the error:

**Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]**

I tried to export my app and filled a valid certificate but then it says:

**Application Not Installed**

Just to test, then I tried an Eclipse application which worked fine. So how can I fix this?

Also installing games from the market also works fine, so technically should'nt my app work also?